# Substitute/Placeholder Variable in R Syntax

Tags: r, syntax, workflow, substitution

I have the following problem:

I need the same syntax over and over again for different variable-sets. 
They all have the same "core" name (for example: variable_1) and different suffixes like:

```
variable_1_a,   variable_1_b,   variable_1_c,   variable_1_d,   variable_1_e, ...
```

since the syntax is large and I need to run it for (example) variables _2, _3, _4, _5, ... and so on, I was wondering whether there is some form of placeholder-expression I could define with the "core" name with which I want to run it each time, instead of copy pasting the whole syntax and substituting every "variable_1" with the next core-name.

For example saving the core name in term !XY! (the "!" is just to represent that it is something atypical) and having that term in the whole syntax with "_a", "_b", "_c" attached

```
!XY!_a, !XY!_b, !XY!_c, !XY!_d, !XY!_e, ...
```

I played around with saving the core-name in an element called XY and pasting it with the endings:

```
XY <- "variable_1"
paste0(as.character(XY),"_a") 
"variable_1_a"
```

OR

```
as.symbol(paste0(as.character(XY),"_a")) 
variable_1_a
```

of course that looks horribly long but that I would accept if it worked to also use it as an expression which I could address to use like a variable: for example to read or write it which results in an error.

```
as.symbol(paste0(as.character(XY),"_a")) <- "test"
Error in as.symbol(paste0(as.character(XY),"_a")) <- "test" : 
could not find function "as.symbol<-"
```

It would be a huge time-saver if there is a chance to write one syntax to fit all procedures!
Thx a lot for your ideas!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your goal, but paste0 is vectorised, so if you wanted a character vector you could use  paste0("variable_1_", letters)?

Comment: the idea is to exchange/substitue only a part of the variable name each time while keeping the ending/suffix - instead of all the copy pasting I was looking for a similar solution with just one change each time - the "letters" were the parts of the variable that have to stay the same, only the first part has to change each time - unfortunately paste0 just creates the right expression, but I can't use it like as if it was plain text - i.e. like a full variable name

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have 5 variables ("variable_1", "variable_2" etc) and 4 letters ("_a", "_b" etc).

We can use `outer` like :

```
n <- 1:5
l <- letters[1:4]

c(outer(n, l, function(x, y) paste("variable", x, y, sep = "_")))
#Or a bit shorter : 
#paste0("variable_", c(outer(n, l, paste, sep = "_")))

#[1] "variable_1_a" "variable_2_a" "variable_3_a" "variable_4_a"
#[5] "variable_5_a" "variable_1_b" "variable_2_b" "variable_3_b"
#[9] "variable_4_b" "variable_5_b" "variable_1_c" "variable_2_c"
#[13] "variable_3_c" "variable_4_c" "variable_5_c" "variable_1_d"
#[17] "variable_2_d" "variable_3_d" "variable_4_d" "variable_5_d"
```

Comment: thx! actually the variable names and "letters" are quite diverse - it was just for illustration. I actually already have them in the dataset and just want to address them in the syntax and work with some of them. Usually I would have to copy-paste the whole syntax and substitute every variable-stem (or core variable name) with the next one while keeping the sufixes _a _b _c etc. at the right places in the syntax...

Comment: can you not just assign them to `n` and `l` then. For example if your dataset is called `df` and column `col` , you can do `n <- df$col`